# Simple question about simple arrays in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

OK this is probably a really stupid question but I can't seem to find the answer.

I know how to sort arrays using sort descriptors but what about a simple array containing only a series of numbers?

For example an array containing the following numbers:
21,3,11,58,32,76,19,45,7,92

I just need the numbers in ascending order.

Comment: Is it a C array containing integers or an `NSArray` containing `NSNumbers`?

Comment: When you say "simple array" do you mean a C array, or an NSArray?

Comment: this may help http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/home/2009/3/25/how-to-sort-an-array-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s.

Fairly simple:

```
NSArray *unorderedNumbers; // assume exists

NSArray *sortedArray = [unorderedNumbers
               sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

(See [sortedArrayUsingSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector%3a)).

This causes the objects (which happen to be numbers) to be compared using [compare:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/compare%3a).

Comment: Simple indeed. Why do the simplest things always seem to hold me up? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The C standard library includes `qsort`

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/